# Pointer or Value

Tags: c, pointers, c99

When I call:

```
write_byte((uint8_t*)0);
```

It passes a null-pointer. How can I modify it to pass a pointer to the literal value 0?

Comment: @Dukeling However, `&0` is illegal. Constants have no address.

Comment: @StoryTeller How can I pass a pointer to the literal value 0, because  I expected that to be: (uint8_t*)&0 with the ampersand, but that doesnt compile.

Comment: `NULL` is often defined as a macro (i.e. `#define`) as `((void *) 0)`.

Comment: @OP, you can't pass a pointer to the literal 0.

Comment: You can't set pointers to any literals at all...

Comment: @Lundin, not exactly. String literals decay to `const char *`

Comment: @StoryTeller, null pointer *is* the correct wording in the standard. As Joachim says, `NULL` is just a macro that expands to a constant value that represents a null pointer *if* it is used in a context where a pointer is expected. `NULL` could well expand to just `0`, so then it wouldn't even always represent a pointer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a compound literal:

```
write_byte(&(int) {0});
```

Comment: Wow. This method works without the need of a variable. It would be great to know if theres any downside to using this?

Comment: @Vector9 the only downside (if we may call it so) I see is compound literals are not supported prior to c99

Answer (score 3):

It passes a NULL pointer.

You cannot take the address of a constant (`&0`). If you want to pass a pointer to the value `0`, you must assign `0` to a variable first.

```
uint8_t i = 0;
write_byte(&i);
```

Comment: I understand that I could solve it with 2 lines, but I wondered if it was possible without a intermediate variabele

Comment: @Joshua, pointers contain memory addresses. What address would the literal zero have?

Comment: @Joshua A literal integer is embedded in the code, and so can not have an address.

Comment: You should not forget *const* for such variables.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `NULL` pointer. `NULL` may be defined as just `0`. The correct wording in the C standard is null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It will sent a `NULL` pointer...

Comment: @Lundin hmm was reading that after I posted the answer.. Corrected.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way at compile time to take the address of a literal, because a literal does not necessarily have an address.

For example, if you write code like `if(0)`, the `0` is likely not allocated anywhere. The compiler will translate it to the machine code instruction "branch if zero" (or more likely "branch always" because of optimization). So the actual zero is embedded into the program code itself.

Because of this, there is no way to know at compile time where a literal is stored. It could be integrated into the program code, or it could reside in read-only memory. You cannot know which, since the compiler itself does not know until it is done translating your source code into machine code.

(I believe you may confuse integer literals with string literals, that always have an address.)

Comment: See my answer, he can do he wantw to achieve using a compound literal.

Comment: @ouah The address of a compound literals will only be valid inside the scope they it was declared though, so there is no particular reason why a compound literal would be better than a plain, local int variable assigned to the value 0. The main issue here seems to be that the OP is confused over where numeric constants end up in the binary executable.

Comment: @Vinska It doesn't make sense to implement a branch never function :) It would essentially be the same as NOP. But it would perhaps qualify for [this list](http://ruthless.zathras.de/fun/top-secret/NewOpCodes.txt).

Comment: @Lundin there is one advantage of passing a compound literal of a scalar type: you don't need to declare an extra useless object. It is shorter and IMHO more elegant.

Comment: @Lundin It's just like `while(0)`, if You had the chance to ever encounter that. Also, this little test program proves `if(0)` is _branch never_ http://pastebin.com/iiHpSCvD (prints _it's a NO!_)

Comment: @ouah The optimized machine code will be _exactly_ the same whether you allocate a local variable with an explicit name or a compound literal. I avoid compound literals just because many C programmers don't know about them.

Comment: @Vinska I'm talking about CPU instructions, aka assembler. It doesn't make sense to create a "branch never" instruction in a CPU. Anyway, my point was that it will get optimized to an unconditional branch.

Comment: @Ludin You should change it to `if(1)`, then. As it might confuse some people and we might even end up getting "why if(0) doesn't work for me?" questions here on SO. And by Murphy's law, some people WILL get confused if it's left as `if(0)`.